# Using enums as parameters in an external file in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, enums

I have an enum named RandomEnum in file foo.h:

```
// foo.h
typedef enum RandomEnum {
  ran_1 = 0,
  ran_2
} RandomEnum;
```

In another file, bar.h, I'm trying to use RandomEnum as a parameter type:

```
// bar.h
#import "foo.h"

@interface bar : NSObject {}
  -(RandomEnum)echo:(RandomEnum)ran;
@end
```

However, the compiler doesn't seem to recognize RandomEnum. Is doing this even possible?

Compiler Error:

```
error: expected ')' before 'RandomEnum'
```

Edit: Added code for foo.h for clarification

Comment: Is that code copied and pasted directly from some source that's showing the problem? Because I just compiled your code and it worked fine.

Comment: Your code compiled just fine on my Mac (10.6). Did you `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` to get NSObject in the scope?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out this is possible after all. My problem had to do with odd cross-includes that weren't direct, but were still present.

In the given example, foo.h included thing.h which included something.h which included bar.h. This cross dependency is what ended up being the problem.

Still, good to know for compiler bugs. Thanks for the responses!

Answer (score 12):

The C construct `enum RandomEnum` does not define a type called `RandomEnum` — it defines a type called `enum RandomEnum`. To be able to write just `RandomEnum` for the type, you need to use a typedef.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I should have clarified that I am using a typedef in foo.h

Answer (score 3):

As @Chuck said, it will work if you do this if you don't want to declare a `typedef`:

```
-(RandomEnum)echo:(enum RandomEnum)ran;
```