# Syntax error in method declaration: Expected ')' before name

Tags: objective-c, ios, syntax-error

I'm very confused about an error I'm getting. I have the following code:

In View1.m I make this call:

```
[iconView addIconWithType:IconTypeStandard];
```

IconView.h

```
typedef enum {
    IconTypeStandard = 0,
    IconTypeNew = 1,
} IconType;

-(void)addIconWithType:(IconType)iconType;
```

IconView.m

```
-(void)addIconWithType:(IconType)iconType {

...

}
```

Icon.h

```
#import "IconView.h"


@interface Icon : UIView {

}

-(Icon *)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame;

-(void)type:(IconType)iconType;
```

That line is causing an error of 'Expected ')' before 'IconType'', but i have no idea why?

Icon.m

```
-(void)type:(IconType)iconType {

...

}
```

Comment: What's the code preceding the line that is causing the error?

Comment: Maybe the problem is above those lines, like not terminating the method before, or not within the @implementation block?

Comment: I put a -(void) test; above that line and commented out the problematic line, then the problem disappears. So it must be a problem with that line.

Comment: May be that 'type' in the beginning of the name of the function is processed like a keyword or other function name?

Comment: Nope, changing it to simply be called 'test' still shows the same error.

Comment: If doing a clean and rebuild doesn't fix it, you might have to start erasing and retyping lines.  That's an old-school solution, but it has worked many times.

Comment: I don't get the file structure. What is in IconView.h? Is the typedef within the @interface declaration? Not sure how Icon and IconView correspond (especially as Icon is a UIView). Things can get tricky if the IconView imports something from Icon which itself imports IconView. import is much better than include, but not perfect.

Comment: i did a clean and rebuild. replacing that (IconType) with (int) works, but it isn't a way around i should take, because i've then got to change it in 2 places every time that bit gets modified.

Comment: If i move the typedef into Icon.h, i get the same error i was getting, but this time in IconView.h. Somehow, despite both having their .h files imported, it's not carrying over properly?

Comment: Check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977205/using-enums-as-parameters-in-an-external-file-in-objective-c). Something wrong with a declaration i think.

Comment: That's it. Thanks Danny. On iconview.h i had imported icon.h, which was causing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing there is a cyclical inclusion. `Icon.h` refers to `IconView.h` and vice versa. Since the `typedef` comes after the import statement in `Icon.h` it is raising the error as it can't find `IconType` yet.

You should probably declare `@class IconView;` and move the `#import "IconView.h"` to `Icon.m`.

Comment: Icon.h has to import IconView.h or it won't be able to see the typedef for `IconType`. An `@class Icon` declaration could go in IconView.h, however.

Comment: I read somewhere in the comments that he had moved the `IconType` declaration to `Icon.h` so I suggested as I did. But thats all done now. It seems to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have a trailing comma in your enum

```
IconTypeNew = 1,    // remove the comma
```

Comment: I changed that, it hasn't fixed it.

Comment: C99 allows a [trailing comma](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/792753/is-the-last-comma-in-c-enum-required) between the last enumerator and the closing brace.

Comment: Not sure why this gets so many upvotes, as the comma is perfectly legal (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/792753/is-the-last-comma-in-c-enum-required). No downvote from me though. :)